# User without a password - how can one login into that account from a non-root account

Tags: sudo, password, useradd, scientific-linux

I have just started to use Scientific Linux (7.0) (although I assume this question might be distribution neutral..). The kernel version is   3.10.0-123.20.1.el7.x86_64.

Coming back to my question.

I switched to `root` account and from there created an new user account `test-account` using the command `adduser test-account`. It didn't prompt me for a password neither did I use the option to provide password. So I guess it's a "without password" account. I can login into this account from root account - which I suppose I'd be able to without providing password even if the test account had a password. However when I try to login into this(test-account) from a third account - it prompts me for password. And just pressing `Enter` doesn't work.

Is it possible to login into this account from a non-root account. Is there a way (without switching to root or using `sudo`) ?

Comment: Your system's policy could be, that a password is required. `adduser` knows the `-p` option to set a password, tho its use is not recommended. So as root, do `passwd test-account` and set a password.

Comment: no, the account is created without password and I'm even able to access it by switching to it from root. only thing I'm not able to do it is to switch to it from a normal user.

Comment: How do you switch to it from root (what command are you using)?

Comment: @roaima `su test-account`. That switches to the `test-account` without a password prompt (which is what would happen even if `test-account` had a password). However, when I try to switch to test account from anther non-privileged user account, kernel asks me for the password with a prompt, and it doesn't accept void (pressing `eneter`)

Comment: You've already received the answer to this. Enjoy.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

By default on enterprise GNU/Linux and its derivatives, the `adduser` command creates a user which is disabled until you explicitly specify a password for that user.

Here is an example on CentOS 6.5, which should be the same as Scientific Linux.

```
 $ sudo adduser test
 $ sudo grep test /etc/shadow
 test:!!:123456:0:99999:7:::
```

that's because in the `/etc/shadow` file, the password field is `!!`, as you can see in the example.

Once you run `passwd` for this account, it will change the user's password and allow the user to be able to login.

So what you should be able to do is the following to have a user without a password, simply create an account then delete the password.

```
 $ sudo adduser test
 $ sudo passwd -d test
 Removing password for user test.
 passwd: Success
 $ su test
 $ whoami
 test
```

now any user should be able to use `su` and login as the user `test` in my example. You will not have to use `sudo` to login as the account.

Although this is possible and you can have an account without a password, it is not advised. If you simply set the password for the user, you should be allowed to login.

```
$ sudo passwd test
[sudo] password for <YOURACCOUNT>:
Changing password for user test.
New password:
Retype new password:
passwd: all authentication tokens updated successfully.
```

Comment: "the adduser command creates a user which is disabled until you explicitly specify a password for that user": how am I able to switch to `test-account`  from root if that is the case (user being disabled)?

Comment: `su test-account`

Comment: I meant to ask is that if the account is disabled, then how is it that I'm able to switch to it using `su` from root?

Comment: the `root` user can `su` into any account that has a shell. If the shell was set to `/bin/false` for example, it would not work. It is just the magic of `root`! many user accounts do not have a valid shell, and are only used to execute specific programs as that user. such as the `apache` user and the apache webserver.

Comment: In Ubuntu 18.04, I can't login as the user with empty password.

Comment: `passwd -d` doesn't work for me neither :(

Answer (score 3):

I have user *guest* which is passwordless. This is its record:

> guest:U6aMy0wojraho:17057:0:99999:7:::

The string "U6aMy0wojraho" is the hashed password of the guest user. When I log in I simply hit enter for the password and the system allows me in.

You should edit the file /etc/shadow and add the above mentioned string right after the username and the first colon.

I copied this string from Ubuntu live CD - its user is paswordless.

Comment: Instead of the accepted answer (`passwd -d ...`) this additionally works with sddm.

Comment: Editing the `/etc/shadow` file directly is risky and usually not recommended. Having a `guest` account it fine, but using the tools to edit the password will reduce potential improper user input or issues with multi-user file saves.

Comment: @NathanMcCoy, I agree that it is risky. But GUI tools do not allow to make empty password - it requires at least 6 or 8 characters. At least, this is the case on Kubuntu that I use.

Comment: @NathanMcCoy yes, one could use `chpasswd -e` to do that more safely: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/472966/32558

Comment: This is great for emergency recovery cases, plug in the hard drive (so to speak) and edit a couple files to fix the machine. Specifically add this user and add him to sudoers temporarily then use a serial console to login and fix whatever broke openssh

Answer (score 3):

**User with empty password**

```
sudo useradd test-user-0
echo test-user-0:U6aMy0wojraho | sudo chpasswd -e
su test-user-0
```

The password prompt still shows unfortunately.

But if you just hit enter without typing anything, and it logins as the user `test-user-0`.

The `-e` flags tells `chpasswd` that the password is already encrypted, and `U6aMy0wojraho` is the hash of the empty string.

Tested on Ubuntu 18.04.

**BusyBox autologin**

On the terminal at least, you don't need to create an user without a password to allow someone to not type their passwords everytime, hacking `inittab` a bit is enough: [How to login automatically without typing the root username or password in Buildroot BusyBox init?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/299408/how-to-login-automatically-without-typing-the-root-username-or-password-in-build)