# How to login automatically without typing the root username or password in Buildroot BusyBox init?

Tags: busybox, buildroot, busybox-init

If I do:

```
git clone git://git.buildroot.net/buildroot
cd buildroot
git checkout 2016.05
make qemu_x86_defconfig
make BR2_JLEVEL=2
qemu-system-x86_64 -M pc -kernel output/images/bzImage -drive file=output/images/rootfs.ext2,if=virtio,format=raw -append root=/dev/vda -net nic,model=virtio -net user
```

I have to type `root` into QEMU before I can use the shell.

How to configure buildroot to skip that and login directly?

Tested on Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**`::respawn:-/bin/sh`**

Using `BR2_ROOTFS_OVERLAY`, modify the guest `/etc/inittab` to contain:

```
::respawn:-/bin/sh
```

instead of the default line of form:

```
console::respawn:/sbin/getty -L console 0 vt100
```

You can copy the default `inittab` from `output/target/etc/inittab` after the build to modify the above line from it.

I found this while studying the [`examples/inittab` in Busybox 1_28_3](https://github.com/mirror/busybox/blob/1_28_3/examples/inittab#L60) and found this, tried it out, and it worked, so it is the best solution I've found so far.

Don't forget the leading dash `-`, or job control actions such as Ctrl + C don't work as mentioned below.

The leading dash `-` gets magically parsed by BusyBox' init: https://github.com/mirror/busybox/blob/1_28_3/init/init.c#L439 and sets up the TTY for the command that follows.

BusyBox also appends the `-` to the beginning or `arg[0]`, which `/bin/sh` interprets as indicating a login shell, which makes it source some init files such as `/etc/profile`. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42291142/895245

The following is equivalent since `console` is the default value:

```
console::respawn:-/bin/sh
```

To login as another user by default, you can use instead:

```
::respawn:-/bin/login -f user0
```

Here is a [sample setup](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/blob/8815312cad053d0284c4d91bfbf36a1e9ea207af/rootfs_overlay/etc/inittab#L8).

**Previous answer: `getty -l`**

After almost two years, I've found it! :-)

Using `BR2_ROOTFS_OVERLAY`, override / create the following files:

/etc/inittab: start from https://github.com/buildroot/buildroot/blob/2018.02/package/busybox/inittab and edit the console line to be:

```
console::respawn:/sbin/getty -n -L -l /loginroot.sh console 0 vt100
```

/loginroot.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec /bin/login root
```

`/bin/login` is the default executable if `-l` is not given. What we did it to create an executable that calls `/bin/login` with the user `root` already specified.

This makes `init` try to log in as the root user by default, and then since the default password is empty (`BR2_TARGET_GENERIC_ROOT_PASSWD`), it automatically logs in.

This technique basically re-implements the `-a <user>` option present in Ubuntu 14.04's `getty`, which BusyBox' implementation doesn't have.

Then, to login as a different user, just run:

```
/bin/login
```

Here is [a sample setup](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/tree/ac67ce36433dbfbab1057af47df9e5f929ac107d#change-user).

**Previous previous answer: `console::respawn:/bin/sh`**

I've [asked on the mailing list](http://lists.busybox.net/pipermail/buildroot/2016-August/168956.html) and Thomas Petazzoni replied that the:

```
/etc/inittab
```

should contain:

```
console::respawn:/bin/sh
```

instead of:

```
console::respawn:/sbin/getty -n -L  console 0 vt100 # GENERIC_SERIAL
```

With `qemu_x86_defconfig`, the `inittab` is being used by Busybox' `init` system, due to `BR2_INIT_BUSYBOX=y`.

This method does have a downside however: just after login, the message shows:

```
/bin/sh can't access tty; job control turned off
```

and as advertised, things like `Ctrl+C` will have no effect.

Comment: Modifying inittab is fine, but I would prefer a solution that only modifies getty. I need to be able to toggle this autologin option, not have it all the time. I can use scripting logic within a custom getty to accomplish this, but not if the solution is strictly within inittab